# Simple Type Inference in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have been looking at type inference in Scala and there are a couple of things I'd like to understand a bit better around why expression/method-return types have to be explicitly declared in a few cases.

**Explicit `return` declaration**

Example (works if `return` keyword is ommitted):

```
def upCase(s: String) = {
  if (s.length == 0)
    return s    // COMPILE ERROR - forces return type of upCase to be declared.
  else
    s.toUpperCase()
}
```

Why can't I use the explicitly typed parameter as a return value without declaring the return type? And that's not only for direct parameter references, just for any 'type-inferable' expression.

**Method overloading**

Example (fails to compile when the second `joiner` method is added):

```
def joiner(ss: List[String], sep: String) = ss.mkString(sep)

def joiner(ss: List[String]) = joiner(strings, " ")   // COMPILE ERROR WHEN ADDED
```

Comment: Perhaps an example illustrating what Scala *should* do and what it *does* do would be a good idea!

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile without explicit return types due to the `joiner` method being overloaded - although again it's not entirely clear why Scala requires this restriction

Comment: I have edited this question in the hope that it will get better treatment from the community. It was a bit argumentative but there *is* an interesting question in here. OP - feel free to rollback (or ask me to rollback) if you're not happy with my edits.

Comment: Thank you, again, for your attention. I didn't want to be 'agressive'; your revision is great.

Comment: My current suspect about these quirks is that designer's concern was to write a single-pass compiler; also, I think, that the compilation speed is involved here. I say that, because the features I want could easily be added causing a (very) little overhead. Actually, I do not know whether 'scalac' is single-pass)

Comment: BTW, my first 'joiner' method was explicitly typed, that's why I mentioned the method signatures.

Comment: @Bubba88 - I removd the explicit typing from the first `joiner` method as it's only when the second is added that the compile problem occurs. When declaring overloaded methods, all of them must have an explicit return type. And it's unhelpful to say (paraphrasing) *"the guys could have done a better job"* - Martin Odersky *wrote the Java compiler*. He is likely to be cleverer than you and me and there will likely be reasons for these "bugs". Better to ask for the reasons, rather than just blindly assuming the compiler-writer was incompetent!

Answer (score 3):

Well most obvious answer is: because it stated in specification see part 6.20 of scala reference. But why it was designed this way is indeed very intresting question. I suspect it connected to the fact that compiler can't predict that expression will be the last one, since return changes execution flow.

**EDIT:**

Consider if return doesn't require explicit return type following code:

```
def bar() = {   
  if(guard())  
    return "SS"  
  else if(gurard1())  
    return true   
  2  
}
```

that return type should bar have in this situation? Well there is option with most common supertype, but I think it will get us to returning Any in many cases. Well this is just my thoughts which may be totally incorrect =)

Comment: -"I suspect it connected to the fact that compiler can't predict that expression will be the last one, since return changes execution flow." ...Don't quite understand)

Comment: However, I guess, you could eliminate the 'return' clauses and it will change nothing. (I mean the ambiguity will be still present)

Comment: Surely declaring `return` explicitly *guarantees* that this is the last expression! Then scala could just do a common-supertype of all of the `return` statements...

Comment: @Bubba88 No, if you eliminate return it will change all other expressions ( in my example just '2' but presume there more) will be executed. 
@oxbow_lakes Nope. What is last expression in code I gave in edit?
It depends of if either of guards fuctions returing true. I alreeady  mentioned most common supertype solution BTW

Answer (score 2):

The type of a function or method is inferred from the type of its last statement. Usually, that's an expression.

Now, "`return`" breaks the control flow. It is an "immediate interrupt", so to speak. Because of that, the normal rules used to infer the type of an expression can't be used anymore. It still could be done, of course, but I'm guessing the cost in compiler complexity was deemed to high for the return.

Here's an example of how the flow is broken:

```
def toNumber(s: String) = {
  if (s == null)
    return ""

  if (s matches """\d+""")
    s.toInt
  else
    0
}
```

Normally, the type of the second `if` statement would be used to infer the type of the whole function. But the `return` on the first `if` introduces a second return point from the function, so this rule won't work.

Comment: I cannot agree, that "the cost in compiler complexity was deemed to high for the return." We can check all return clauses and paths, leading to them at compile time; after all - doesn't the compiler need to check the type of every expression in function body to resolve the final one?

Comment: very silly example would be declary two 'typeless' variables (initialized by numbers) in a function and multiplying them as the final expression: the compiler must check both variables before telling the result's type, cause it can be both integer or float or long etc. I don't actually know 'scalac'-s type inference algorithm, but something tells me, that recursive drivedown cannot be actually avoided.

Comment: The type inferences works statement by statement. If something cannot be figured out by the end of the statement, then it barfs, even if something further on would have provided enough information to decide. Now, the type inferencer algorithm is likely the most complex part of the Scala compiler and, in fact, it is not even spec'ed, so extending it is not a trivial task, and the increase in complexity has consequences for the correctness and maintainability of the compiler. The line for that, as far as I can see, is drawn on a loose cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: Daniel, sorry but it seems that you're not completely right. We actually can (automatically) infer what is the type of 'return' expression, cause all we need is the types of expressions preceding it. Coupled with that 'the type inferences works statement by statement', i think it's easy to get - we do not need to calculate any further than 'return' clause!) Cause, as we know, the return statement is always the last statement in execution flow. And about specs, Nikolay said: "Well most obvious answer is: because it stated in specification see part 6.20 of scala reference.."

Comment: The `return` statement is not always the last. See my example for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Type inference infers the return type of a method when it can, which is more or less in any case that the method isn't recursive.

Your example would work if you changed it to:

```
def upCase(s: String) = {
 if (s.length == 0)
   s    // note: no return
 else
   s.toUpperCase()
}
```

I don't know offhand why the return changes this.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** - *this answer was directed to the question as it was originally posted*

Scala's type inference already does infer the return type of a method / expression:

```
scala> def foo(s : String) = s + " Hello"
foo: (String)java.lang.String

scala> var t = foo("World")
t: java.lang.String = World Hello
```

and:

```
scala> def bar( s : String) = s.toInt
bar: (String)Int

scala> var i = bar("3")
i: Int = 3
```

and:

```
scala> var j = if (System.getProperty("user.name") == "oxbow") 4 else "5".toInt
j: Int = 5
```

**EDIT** - I didn't realize that the inclusion of the `return` keyword meant that the return type of an expression had to be explicitly declared: I've pretty much stopped using `return` myself - but it's an interesting question. For the `joiner` example, the return type must be declared because of overloading. Again, I don't know the details as to why and would be interested to find out. I suspect a better-phrased question subject would elicit an answer from the likes of James Iry, Dan Spiewak or Daniel Sobral.

Comment: return is superfluous and can be ommitted - although it's a good question to ask *"Why does an explicit return require an explicit return type?"*

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the method overloading (lack of) inference is related to the similar problem with recursive calls, because if the overloaded methods doesn't call each other, it works perfectly:

```
  def joiner1(ss: List[String], sep: String) = ss.mkString(sep)
  def joiner(ss: List[String], sep: String) = ss.mkString(sep)
  def joiner(ss: List[String]) = joiner1(ss, " ")
```

There's two overloaded joiner methods, but the types are inferred correctly the code compiles.

Comment: I do think so, too. But I wonder how method overloading is related to recursion; I mean, overloaded method is just two or more different methods without any logical relationship.

Comment: Have you try asking the question in the Scala mailing list? You'll get either the why or a fix for the compiler :)